# Breakpoint in ASP.NET MVC Razor view will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints, iis-express, pdb-files

I can't get a breakpoint in a Razor view to be hit in Visual Studio 2013 while debugging in IIS Express.

This is the view and unreachable breakpoint:

[image]

Looking at the modules I see that the latest PDB file has been loaded:

[image]

And the folder

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\53ff8402\967c7053\assembly\dl3\f3c59a34\6698ffde_b452cf01
```

has the latest version of the DLL and PDF files:

```
ITVizion.VizionLogs.WeeklyLogs.Web.DLL
ITVizion.VizionLogs.WeeklyLogs.Web.PDB
```

I have already cleaned the solution, wiped the project's `bin` folder, restarted Visual Studio, etc but it still won't hit the breakpoint.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't believe it guys... wasted almost 1 hour on this. I was trying to debug the wrong view in the wrong path.

I set a breakpoint in this view:

```
C:\ITVizion\VizionLogs\ITVizion.VizionLogs.WeeklyLogs.Web\Views\Error\ServerError.cshtml
```

but actually I was trying to debug this view:

```
C:\ITVizion\VizionLogs\ITVizion.VizionLogs.WeeklyLogs.Web\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml
```

After I placed a breakpoint in the correct view, although it showed the message about the breakpoint would not be hit, the `Debugger` actually hit the breakpoint during runtime! :D