# Code called by ASP.NET MVC Razor breakpoint symbols not being loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

First of all: I cleaned my solution. Closed Visual Studio. Deleted the Temporary ASP.NET Files. I've also seen [Breakpoint in ASP.NET MVC Razor view will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924809/breakpoint-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view-will-not-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loade) but that's not the case for me.

Here is my code:

[image]

This called is actually called by my ASP.NET MVC Razor page, and the very call to this method's breakpoint is hit. When I try to step in, it just doesn't step into the method. Symbols for this code is never being loaded. I haven't changed any debugging/symbol etc. settings.

Why aren't the symbols loading?

Comment: Closing VS should close IIS Express but you may want to check and make sure that also closes? doubting it's that easy though :)

Comment: Are you running with DEBUG defined?

Comment: Is the code in a class file or within the cshtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no valid idea why, but when I turned off `Just My Code`, it worked! It is an extension class for `IHtmlHelper`, and I think Visual Studio somehow thinks it's not my code. I know it sounds stupid but disabling it just worked instantly. Maybe Visual Studio 2015 should be nominated as the most buggy IDE of the century.

Comment: Just my code is disabled and i'm having the same issue in visual studio 2022